# when click run button on visual studio 2015 Resharper changes my codes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

How to disable resharper formatting code option when click run button on visual studio 2015

code before  saving

[image: looks like this]

code after saving

[image: looks like this]

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to options and try one of these settings. Notice the preview window on the bottom.

For other issues you have, please check the `Blank Lines` and `Line Breaks and Wrapping` sections in the same options node.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bartosz for your replay .This doesn't work .Resharper behaves like backspace .

Comment: Yes.I have changed images above please review

Comment: That is a different setting and a different bheaviour that you have changed. Also, please don't edit the posts like that, because the original issue is gone now

Comment: the behavior is the same of previews if cursor stays inside eny word inside visual studio code window resharper does not change code but if the cursor stays after  ";" or  " {"  or "}"  and some an other symbols  it behave like backspace

Comment: See my update - I suppose you have specified the rules incorrectly.

Comment: I haven't changed anything it is default behavior

Comment: Thanks Bartosz. Blank Lines and Line Breaks and Wrapping sections in the same options node slove this problem

Comment: @NurlanMikayilov - cool - feel free to set the answer as accepted:)